# Viterbi Algorithm Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, viterbi

I'm trying to implement Viterbi Algorithm in Matlab and for some reason on my induction part after the first pass of i the alpha turns to 0. I.E. 
V =

```
0.7000         0
0.0980         0
```

V =

```
0.7000         0
     0         0
```

V =

```
0.7000         0
     0    0.1680
```

V =

```
0.7000         0
     0         0
```

Also, the BestPath just results in a bunch of 0's with a one at the end and I don't know why.

My code:

```
function [ViterbiScore,BestPath] = Viterbi(A,B,Pi,Obv)

%INPUTS:
%Obv = Observation sequence
%A = Transition probability matrix
%B = Emission matrix
%Pi = initial probability matrix

%OUTPUT:
%ViterbiScore
%BestPath = Best-state sequence as a vector of complex numbers.

T=length(Obv);
N=length(A(1,:));

%Initilization
for i=1:N
    V(1,i)=Pi(i)*B(i,Obv(1));
    BT(1,i)=0;
end

%Induction
for t=2:T
    for j=1:N
        for i=1:N
            V(t,j)=max(V(t-1,i)*A(i,j))*B(j,Obv(t))
            [rndm,BT(t,j)]=max(V(t-1,i)*A(i,j));
        end
    end
end

%Termination
for i=1:N
    [ViterbiScore,BestPath(T)] = max(V(T,i));
end

for t=(T-1):1
    BestPath(t)=BT(t+1,BestPath(t+1));
end
```

Comment: You should perhaps ask this on DSP StackExchange: Not many of us know how the Viterbi algorithm works. http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank You, I actually figured out what was wrong anyway

Comment: Cool.  If that's the case, either delete your answer as questions being solved due to simple bugs are not useful, or provide your own answer to the question below and when you're able to do so, mark your answer and accept it.  Good luck!

Comment: @FlameArc Do you know there's a Viterbi decoder function [`vitdec`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vitdec.html) in the Communications Toolbox? It allows setting the traceback length, soft/hard decoding, source "flush" bits...

Comment: @LuisMendo: Of course, calling a black box (especially one complicated by additional options) does not really help with understanding the concept, which is presumably the point of implementing it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I hadn't _presumed_ that. But maybe you are right and that's the OP's intention. And yes, doing it yourself definitely helps (I remember how much I learned from doing exactly this by myself many years ago)